# Why inflating Navigation view give NoSuchFieldError of No static field MenuItem_iconTintMode?

Tags: java, android, navigationview

Currently i'm facing an error with the navigation View of my project, when the app try to show up just stops and haven't found any answer that could help me.

Here is the error.

```
09-11 18:54:23.160 16755-16755/co.cloudtechnologys.www.contol_academic_student E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: co.cloudtechnologys.www.contol_academic_student, PID: 16755
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{co.cloudtechnologys.www.contol_academic_student/co.cloudtechnologys.www.contol_academic_student.Views.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3319)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3415)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:229)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7406)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:551)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
        at co.cloudtechnologys.www.contol_academic_student.Views.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:138)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6904)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3266)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3415) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:229) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7406) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:657)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:776)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:716)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:847)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:527)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
        at co.cloudtechnologys.www.contol_academic_student.Views.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:138) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6904) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1136) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3266) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3415) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:229) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7406) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:631)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:776) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:716) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:847) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:527) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
        at co.cloudtechnologys.www.contol_academic_student.Views.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:138) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6904) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1136) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3266) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3415) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:229) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7406) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
     Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No static field MenuItem_iconTintMode of type I in class Landroid/support/v7/appcompat/R$styleable; or its superclasses (declaration of 'android.support.v7.appcompat.R$styleable' appears in /data/app/co.cloudtechnologys.www.contol_academic_student-1/base.apk)
        at android.support.v7.view.SupportMenuInflater$MenuState.readItem(SupportMenuInflater.java:435)
        at android.support.v7.view.SupportMenuInflater.parseMenu(SupportMenuInflater.java:177)
        at android.support.v7.view.SupportMenuInflater.inflate(SupportMenuInflater.java:127)
        at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.inflateMenu(NavigationView.java:248)
        at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:172)
        at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:98)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:631) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:776) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:716) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:847) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:527) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
        at co.cloudtechnologys.www.contol_academic_student.Views.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:138) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6904) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1136) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3266) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3415) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:229) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7406) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

everything was working fine before added the realm library but i needed to to make a new section of the app, i have tried recreating the entire project but doesn't work, ends up in the same error.

here is my **app module**.

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    apply plugin: 'realm-android'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 27
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "co.cloudtechnologys.www.contol_academic_student"
            minSdkVersion 16
            targetSdkVersion 27
            versionCode 39
            versionName "1.0.35"
            testInstrumentationRunner 
    "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
    'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
        configurations.all {
            resolutionStrategy {

            }
        }

    compileOptions {
        targetCompatibility 1.8
        sourceCompatibility 1.8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:12.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
    implementation 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-android:4.48'
    implementation 'it.sephiroth.android.library.picasso:picasso:2.5.2.4b'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.0.0'
    implementation 'com.akexorcist:RoundCornerProgressBar:2.0.3'
    implementation 'com.toptoche.searchablespinner:searchablespinnerlibrary:1.3.1'
    implementation 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:2.1.3'
    implementation 'uk.co.samuelwall:material-tap-target-prompt:1.7.0'
    implementation 'com.github.sundeepk:compact-calendar-view:1.9.9'
    implementation 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:12.0.1'
    implementation 'com.github.thomper:sweet-alert-dialog:v1.4.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.shimmer:shimmer:0.2.0'
    implementation files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
}
```

this is the **activity_main** that have a navigation view.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="#ffff">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/colegioTextDrawable"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@color/md_grey_500" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/version"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/colegioTextDrawable"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@color/md_grey_400"
                android:textSize="10dp" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**Main Activity Class** it's a lot of code in this one so i will post the parts where is used.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private RealmConfiguration realmConfiguration;
private DrawerLayout drawer;
private NavigationView navigationView;

private ActualizarVersionController mActualizarVersionController;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    mContext = this;
}

    private void setupNavigationDrawerContent(NavigationView navigationView) {

        View headerView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
        TextView emailText = (TextView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.IDnombreDraw);
        tipoU = (TextView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.TipoUsuarioNH);
navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(
                menuItem -> {
                    switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                        case R.id.inasistencia:
                            menuItem.setChecked(true);
                            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Inasistencias.class);
                            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.left_int, R.anim.left_out);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            finish();

                            return true;
                        case R.id.tesoreria:
                            menuItem.setChecked(true);
                            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                            Intent intentT = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ExpandibleTesoreria.class);
                            startActivity(intentT);
                            finish();

                            break;
                        case R.id.perfil:
                            //menuItem.setChecked(true);
                            //drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                            return true;
                        case R.id.ajuste:
                            menuItem.setChecked(true);
                            Intent inte = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Ajustes.class);
                            inte.putExtra("Menu", "menu");
                            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.left_int, R.anim.left_out);
                            startActivity(inte);
                            finish();
                            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                            return true;
                        case R.id.CerrarS:
                            menuItem.setChecked(true);
                            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Login.class));
                            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
                            Principal.cerrarSessionToken(MainActivity.this, getString(R.string.url), Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this));
                            MainActivity.this.finish();
                            DataBaseHelper dataBaseHelper = new DataBaseHelper(MainActivity.this);
                            dataBaseHelper.onResetUsuarios();
                            dataBaseHelper.onResetEstudiantes();
                            dataBaseHelper.onResetSincronizacion();
                            dataBaseHelper.onResetToken();
                            dataBaseHelper.onResetModelos();
                            dataBaseHelper.onResetCalendario();
                            dataBaseHelper.onResetPromedioEstudiante();
                            dataBaseHelper.onResetPeriodo();
                            dataBaseHelper.onResetProcesos();
                            dataBaseHelper.onResetSubProcesos();
                            dataBaseHelper.onResetMinMaxEstadoAcademico();
                            dataBaseHelper.onResetProcesosDim();
                            dataBaseHelper.onResetSubProcesosDim();
                            dataBaseHelper.onResetAsignaturas();
                            dataBaseHelper.onResetConfiguracion();
                            dataBaseHelper.onResetHorarioEstudiante();
                            dataBaseHelper.onResetCantidadEventos();
                            dataBaseHelper.onResetMensajeria();
                            dataBaseHelper.onResetEstudianteBD();
                            dataBaseHelper.onResetItemTiendaVirtual();
                            dataBaseHelper.onResetDetalleItemTiendaVirtual();
                            dataBaseHelper.onResetBalanceTienda();
                            dataBaseHelper.onResetEscalaValorativa();
                            MainActivity.clearBadge(MainActivity.this);
                            Realm.deleteRealm(realmConfiguration);
                            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                            return true;
                        //Excusas por el movil
                        //    case R.id.excusas:
                        //            Intent i = new Intent(Inasistencias.this, ResponderExcusas.class);
                        //        startActivity(i);
                        //        finish();
                        //        return true;
                        case R.id.cambioHijo:
                            if (tipo.equals("6")) {
                                menuItem.setChecked(true);
                                Intent intentCH = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Principal.class);
                                startActivity(intentCH);
                                DataBaseHelper dataBaseHelper2 = new DataBaseHelper(MainActivity.this);
                                dataBaseHelper2.onResetSincronizacion();
                                dataBaseHelper2.onResetEstudiantes();
                                dataBaseHelper2.onResetPromedioEstudiante();
                                dataBaseHelper2.onResetPeriodo();
                                dataBaseHelper2.onResetProcesos();
                                dataBaseHelper2.onResetSubProcesos();
                                dataBaseHelper2.onResetMinMaxEstadoAcademico();
                                dataBaseHelper2.onResetProcesosDim();
                                dataBaseHelper2.onResetSubProcesosDim();
                                dataBaseHelper2.onResetAsignaturas();
                                dataBaseHelper2.onResetConfiguracion();
                                dataBaseHelper2.onResetHorarioEstudiante();
                                dataBaseHelper2.onResetItemTiendaVirtual();
                                dataBaseHelper2.onResetDetalleItemTiendaVirtual();
                                dataBaseHelper2.onResetBalanceTienda();
                                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.left_int, R.anim.left_out);
                                finish();
                                drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                            } else {
                                //menuItem.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                menuItem.setVisible(false);
                            }
                            break;
                        case R.id.agenda:
                            Intent intentA = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Agenda.class);
                            startActivity(intentA);
                            finish();
                            menuItem.setChecked(true);
                            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                            break;
                        case R.id.mensajeria:
                            Intent intentM = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Mensajeria.class);
                            intentM.putExtra("Menu", "Menu");
                            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.left_int, R.anim.left_out);
                            startActivity(intentM);
                            finish();
                            menuItem.setChecked(true);
                            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                            break;
                        case R.id.estadoacademicom:
                            menuItem.setChecked(true);
                            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                            Intent intentE;
                            if (coddimenval != null && !coddimenval.equals("") && !coddimenval.equals("null")) {

                                if (Integer.parseInt(coddimenval) > 0) {
                                    intentE = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Activity_Dimension_Valorativa.class);
                                    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.left_int, R.anim.left_out);
                                } else {
                                    intentE = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Estado_Academico_Estudiantes.class);
                                    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.left_int, R.anim.left_out);
                                }
                                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.left_int, R.anim.left_out);
                                startActivity(intentE);
                                finish();
                            } else {
                                Funciones f = new Funciones();
                                f.Alerta("Necesitas descargar la información del estudiante", MainActivity.this);
                            }
                            break;
                        case R.id.horario:
                            Intent i;
                            i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, horarioEstudianteVista.class);
                            startActivity(i);
                            finish();
                            menuItem.setChecked(true);
                            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                            break;
                        case R.id.excusas:
                            Intent i2;
                            i2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ResponderExcusas.class);
                            startActivity(i2);
                            finish();
                            menuItem.setChecked(true);
                            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                            break;
                        case R.id.incidente:
                            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Incidencias.class));
                            finish();
                            menuItem.setChecked(true);
                            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                            break;
                        case R.id.tienda:
                            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Alimentacion.class));
                            finish();
                            menuItem.setChecked(true);
                            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                            break;
                        case R.id.transporte:
                            menuItem.setChecked(true);
                            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                            Intent t = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TransporteActivity.class);
                            startActivity(t);
                            finish();
                            return true;
                        case R.id.enfermeria:
                            Intent enfermeria1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, EnfermeriaActivity.class);
                            startActivity(enfermeria1);
                            finish();
                            menuItem.setChecked(true);
                            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                            break;
                        case R.id.aula:
                            Intent aula = new Intent(MainActivity.this, aulaVirtual.class);
                            startActivity(aula);
                            finish();
                            menuItem.setChecked(true);
                            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                            break;
                    }
                    return true;
                });
}
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: better if you also include your activity java source.

Comment: @LeandroKeenZapa i have added part of the code where navigation view is used, please if you could watch it. thanks.

Comment: check your menu xml code in res->menu. also its a good way to put setNavigationItemSelectedListener inside onCreate().